# is it possible to get insights for an OpenGraph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

I want to get insights for a specific OpenGraph object (such as total impressions, clicks, etc..)

I'm getting the object id for the url by using FQL `SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url=......`

Once I have the object id, is it possible to get insights for it ?

I tried with https://graph.facebook.com/objectid/insights without too much success..

according to Facebook's documentation, FQL can be used to get insights for a specific story, but I don't have any story ids..

is it possible to get those insights or do I have to store the action id for each generated action and get insights for those recorded action ids ? (btw - is an action id == story id ?)

btw - I'm doing everything with an app access token.

Comment: Try different access tokens and see if you get anything. Certain insights are only available to admins of an object. Others are only available if you authenticate as a page. For insights, the Graph API and FQL both return the same things.

Comment: but can I get insights for an OpenGraph object by its id or do I have to store the published action ids and get insights for those actions ?